# Merging spans is very slow when using the model "en_core_web_md" of Spacy

Tags: merge, model, spacy

Thank spacy for providing the very nice library. I found a question: merging span very slow(about 200ms) when using the model "en_core_web_md". The code is as follows:

```
 import spacy
 import time

 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
 doc = nlp("I need to speak with one of your technicians")

 st = time.time()
 with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
     retokenizer.merge(doc[0:4])

 print(time.time() - st)
 print([w.text for w in doc])
```

This is fast(about 12ms) while using the model:"en_core_web_sm" or "en_core_web_lg".
The environment:

```
      spacy                    2.3.2
      en-core-web-md           2.3.1
      Python                   3.8.6 
      Ubuntu                   16.04.7 LTS
```

I tried to add:

```
   doc.tensor = None
```

before retokenize according to [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3300), but it did not work. Anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A [reprex] may help

Comment: Thank Sergey Bushmanov. I reedited and posted the whole example. Please see it if possible.